# Scan the user input and then work with these letters

Tags: beginner, c, homework

The program scans a maximum of 10 chars from user and then offers you 4 options what you can do with that array. Options are:

- 0 = quit the program,
- 1 = prints whole array,
- 2 = count all the small letters,
- 3 = prints only the numbers,
- 4 = change the small letters with the big ones and via versa.

This is my homework for school, so the interface needs to be in Czech. I think that overall it's quite good but I want to improve!!

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {

    int char_count = 10;
    char input_chars[char_count];
    int i = 0;
    int applied_numb = 1;
    int last_index;
    int amount_small_char = 0;
    int ascii_code;

    printf("Zadejte maximalne 10 znaku" );
    do {
        printf(" \n Zadejte %d z %d: ", i, char_count);
        input_chars[i] = getchar();
        getchar();
        i++;
            if(i == char_count) {
                printf("Zadali jste maximalni pocet znaku. \n");
        }
    } while(i < char_count && input_chars[i - 1] != '.' );

    if(input_chars[i - 1] == '.')
    {
        // in case of last element is "." substract 2 from last index(because we used do while cycle (i++))
        last_index = i - 2;
    }
    else
    {
        last_index = i - 1;
    }


    while (applied_numb != 0 && applied_numb <= 4 && applied_numb >= 0)
    {
        printf("Vyberte si co chcete s danymi cisli provest: \n 0) konec programu \n 1) vypis \n 2) pocet malych pismen \n 3) vypsat jen cislice \n 4) zmenit mala/velka pismena\n");
        scanf ("%i", &applied_numb);

        switch (applied_numb)
        {
            case 0:
                printf ("KONEC PROGRAMU, SEE YOU SOON :) ");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("Vypis vaseho vstupuje: ");
                for(i = 0; i <= last_index; i++)
                {
                    printf(" %c",input_chars[i]);
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                for (i = 0; i <= last_index; i++)
                {
                    ascii_code = (int)input_chars[i];
                    if (ascii_code >= 97 && ascii_code <= 122)
                    {
                        amount_small_char = amount_small_char + 1;
                    }
                }
                printf("Pocet malych pismen ve vasim vstupu je:  %d", amount_small_char);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Tyto cislice jsou ve vasem vstupu:");
                for (i = 0; i <= last_index; i++)
                {
                    ascii_code = (int)input_chars[i];
                    if (ascii_code >= 48 && ascii_code <= 57)
                    {
                        printf(" %c", input_chars[i]);

                    }
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Zmena na mala/velka pismena vypada takto:");
                for (i = 0; i <= last_index; i++)
                    {
                        ascii_code = (int)input_chars[i];
                        if (ascii_code >= 97 && ascii_code <= 122)
                        {
                            ascii_code = ascii_code - 32;
                            printf(" %c", ascii_code);
                        }
                        else if(ascii_code >= 65 && ascii_code <= 90)
                        {
                            ascii_code = ascii_code + 32;
                            printf(" %c", ascii_code);
                        }
                        else if((ascii_code <= 64 && ascii_code >= 0) ||
                                (ascii_code >= 91 && ascii_code <= 96) ||
                                (ascii_code >= 123))
                        {
                            printf(" %c", input_chars[i]);
                        }
                    }
                break;
        }

        printf("\n  \n ------------------------------------- \n \n ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You just wrote this program and it's perfectly clear in your mind, imagine to come back after 1 year: you will need to re-read everything to understand what it is doing because everything is in one big function (which is also hard to test, something you will definitely love to have when writing production code).

First of all let's split the logic into smaller functions, do it in small steps:

```
#define MAX_INPUT_LENGTH 10

int main()
{
    char input[MAX_INPUT_LENGTH + 1] = {0};
    if (!read_input_text(input, MAX_INPUT_LENGTH))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    while (1)
    {
        print_menu();

        switch (read_menu_option())
        {
            case 0:
                puts("KONEC PROGRAMU, SEE YOU SOON :) ");
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            case 1:
                print_input(input);
                break;
            case 2:
                print_count_lowercase_letters(input);
                break;
            case 3:
                print_digits(input);
                break;
            case 4:
                print_input_toggled(input);
                break;
            default:
                puts("Invalid option.");
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can further split this code and menu may be well handled with a dictionary of functions to call (it will be easier to extend) but I think you understand the point. Few things to note:

- I initialized `input` to zero, now you do not need to `last_index` because you simply can use `strlen()`. Also to print the string is as simple as `puts(input)` because you  have a valid null terminated C string (note the extra array item added to hold the string terminator).
- Variable-length arrays are a subtle thing, you may avoid them unless they're absolutely required.
- I'm using `EXIT_SUCCESS` instead of 0, it's a small thing but I think it helps to make the intent clear (and it's easier to search...)
- I'm using `puts()` instead of `printf()` when I *simply* need to print a string to `stdout`: it's faster, easier and better communicate the intent (compiler may also detect what you're doing and use `puts()` for you, BTW).

Now let's examine the *core logic*. As you can already imagine the input function might be simplified:

```
bool read_input_text(char* input, size_t maximumLength)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i < maximumnLength; ++i)
    {
        int c = getchar();

        if (c == EOF)
            return false;

        if (c == '.')
            return true;

        input[i] = (char)c;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Few notes:

- I'm using a `for` loop to read needed characters, I think it's shorter and easier to understand than the equivalent `while`.
- I check for `EOF`, user may press CTRL+D/CTRL+Z or `stdin` may be redirected and input file may be too short. As Chux noted you may consider `EOF` when string is still empty as a valid input (returning `true`).
- When user type `.` I do not write it to `input` and because it's already zeroed then I simply can exit.
- I'm using `bool` and other macros defined in `stdbool.h`.
- I'm not allocating memory in this function, you may also change it to be `char* read_input_text()` but it's less error-prone (in bigger programs) to have a clear ownership for dynamically allocated memory.
- `read_input_text()` is assuming that `input` is already zeroed. In *true* production code this should not be the case (less function interface requirements mean less bugs...) You may try to change it to append a trailing 0 where appropriate (tnx Chux, again, to point this out.)

How to count for lowercase letters? You're doing that manually but it's little bit hard to read because you're using magic numbers, let's try to write a small function:

```
int count_lowercase_characters(char* text)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (size_t i=0; i < strlen(text); ++i)
    {
        if (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z')
            ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Using `'a'` and `'z'` instead of their ASCII values makes code easier to understand (I personally do not remember ASCII codes...) and less error-prone. But, hey...isn't it a very common task? There is a standard function for that, let's use it:

```
int count_lowercase_characters(const char* text)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (size_t i=0; i < strlen(text); ++i)
    {
        if (islower((unsigned char)text[i])
            ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Note:

- I'm directly using `strlen()` and loop variable is `size_t`. Note that it's not mandatory for `size_t` to be equivalent to `int`!
- I'm using `int` even if `unsigned` (or even better `size_t`) *might* be more appropriate, don't go into academic discussions about this...
- I declare `text` as `const char*`, I'm not going to modify the pointed value. Later you may want to declare it as `const char* const` but no need to go that far, now (also consider to declare it as `char const *`, it may be easier to *pick* when beginning).
- I'm casting `text[i]` to `unsigned char`, if your compiler is aliasing `char` to `unsigned char` then you do not need it. See also [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21805970/2410359)

To write `print_count_lowercase_letters()` should now be trivial. As you can imagine there is also a similar function `isdigit()` to determine if a `char` is a digit (0..9) to use in `print_digits()`.

The last function we have to go through is the one to *toggle* the case:

```
if (islower(text[i]))
    text[i] = toupper(text[i]);
else if (isupper(text[i]))
    text[i] = tolower(text[i]);
```

In this case I'm toggling the original string but you may simply write it to `stdout`. Note that you're using `printf()` to print a single character, there is an easier way:

```
if (islower((unsigned char)text[i]))
    putchar(toupper(text[i]));
else if (isupper((unsigned char)text[i]))
    putchar(tolower(text[i]));
else
    putchar(text[i]);
```

Notes:

- I'm using `putchar()` to print a single character to `stdout`. Easier and faster.
- I'm using `islower()` and `isupper()` to determine the case of the character. If you can't use these library functions then write your own function to reuse.
- I'm using `tolower()` and `toupper()` to perform case conversion. Again if you can't use them then write your own, you will gain in legibility.
- Last `else` has been greatly simplified, string is user input then it already contains printable characters, everything else which is not a letter should simply go untouched.
- I didn't write it but the loop is similar to the previous function `for (size_t i=0; i < strlen(text); ++i)`. See very last paragraph for more info.

---

In this examples I didn't consider any *optimization*, you will soon learn that `strlen(text)` as condition in a `for` loop is relatively terrible from a performance point of view (because outside very simple cases compiler isn't able to determine that it can be optimized and evaluated just once). The same loop may then be rewritten (few solutions ordered for complexity+speed).

To evaluate `strlen(text)` just once:

```
for (size_t i=0, n = strlen(text); i < n; ++i)
```

To *manually* stop when encountering string terminator:

```
for (size_t i=0; text[i] != 0; ++i)
```

To fully use pointers arithmetic:

```
for (char *p = text; *p; ++p)
```

Comment: +1, but please `for (size_t i=0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)` or even better: `for(char *p = text; *p; p++)`

Comment: @firda OP is still studying, I left out any _optimization_ in favor of clarity but yes, I agree it is worth to be mentioned (at least for future readers!)

Comment: I agree that performance optimization is not on the table of this review, but I still think that you, as a reviewer, should not offer such code. I actually like your version with text[i] the most, apropriate for OP's level of knowledge (no pointers) and you already zeroed the input array to use strlen because it searches for terminator. So maybe: `for (size_t i=0; text[i] != 0; i++)` would be most educational.

Comment: I agree, changed that. I admit I admire CS/programming teachers. They have to face these trade offs and issues every day! Definitely not an easy job.

Comment: `read_input_text()` relies on prior code to insure a null character, better to explicitly append it in the function.  IMO, a `c == EOF` should return `true` if no prior characters read, else it is just the end of input like `'.'` - yet this is a corner case.

Comment: Note: `islower(text[i])` is UB if `text[i] < 0`.  Consider `islower((unsigned char) text[i])` to match the range of values returned/saved from `getchar()`.  OP is using Czech, so values outside the ASCII range are reasonable to consider and code for.

Comment: "I'm using int even if unsigned might be more appropriate, don't go into academic discussions about this..."  OK, yet `size_t` would be better even than `unsigned`.

Comment: @chux 1a) It's right, admittedly my purpose there was to _introduce_ `= {0}` to the OP (again it is worth to be mentioned, I'll edit). 1b) Same reason, it's for learning then I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible (not sure if this oversimplified educational approach is right, BTW) 2) You're right, my bad! 3) Hmmmmm I'm not sure, I like the reasoning behind C++ choice to do not use `size_t` for counting purposes (for example with `std::count()`) and I think some of them apply in C as well. It's my debatable personal opinion, for sure.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Interesting thought about using a return type like `std::count()` that returns some "signed integral type".  So code could still use `size_t count ;` to perform that count (as that will never overflow, unlike `int`).  Then perform a range test if desired just prior to converting and returning that "signed integral type".  e.g. `if (count > INT_MAX) TBD_Handler();  else return (int) count;`

Comment: @chux yes. Not that I'm saying it's even useful in this specific case (we're counting characters and it's our private function then `size_t` like any other `str*()` function is absolutely appropriate.)

Comment: I would use `int` for this review consistently, no `unsingned` or `size_t` (which is `unsigned` and has `ssize_t` counterpart). It is _ok_ to use `int` which can hold +-2GB. The user can input atmost 10 characters, so why bother about the range 2GB..4GB?!

Comment: @chux: where the hell did you get that passing anything to `islower` is undefined behaviour? No, it is not. And passing anything to `tolower` may be locale-dependendt but the result is always either _lowered_ or _original_. It is not specified what `char` is, it can be `signed` or `unsigned` (and compiler usually has option for this), but please, be careful when invoking UB ;)

Comment: @firda C specifies UB in certain cases with `is...()` funcitons.  C11dr 7.4 Character handling specifies for several `is...()` functions: "In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.".  So with a signed `char` and `char ch = -2; islower(ch)` is UB - unless it happened to match `EOF`.

Comment: @chux: No, even -1 is converted to 255 when converting to `unsigned char`

Comment: @firda `islower(-1)` does not convert the -1 to an `unsigned char`.  With the common case that `EOF == -1`, `islower(-1)` returns 0 because `EOF` is not a lower case letter.  `islower(int ch)` is defined for typically 257 different inputs.  There is no conversion to `unsigned char` of the `int` argument.  [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21805970/2410359) and [argument of isupper/islower etc. needs to be converted to unsigned char](https://github.com/opencog/link-grammar/issues/347) may be useful.

Comment: @chux I incorporated that link in my answer, I hope you don't mind. Soon I'll have to change this to a _community wiki_...

Comment: @chux: the possible/accepted meanings of such standards will never stop surprising me, just like politicians. Try `unsigned char c = -3` - what do you get? Nevermind, *common sense* does not work here.

Comment: @firda `unsigned char c = -3` does not apply to issue of passing a negative value to `islower(int ch)`.  `is...()` functions work well with the results of `fgetc(). getchar(), etc. and work well with platforms that have a unsigned `char`.  Unfortunately `is...()` functions also work with `EOF`.  Had it not been for that long ago choice, certainly the hoped for functionality of the `int ch` argument getting a `unsigned char` conversion before evaluation would have been realized.